# oracle analytics how to return this rows

Tags: oracle

I am writing this query for DWH purpose.

```
SELECT 
   YEAR
  ,MONTH
  ,WEEK
  ,C.CPG_PK         CPG
  ,C.DEP_PK         DEPT
  ,T.CUST_ID        CUST_ID
  ,D1.R_ID          R_ID
  ,Decode(d2.AT_CODE,'3',FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE))    AS P1
  ,decode(d2.AT_CODE,'2',FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE))    AS IC
  ,decode(d2.AT_CODE,'1',FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE))    AS B1
  ,decode(FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE), 2 , d2.AT_CODE)    AS P2
  ,decode(FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE), 5 , d2.AT_CODE)    AS B2
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT A.CUST_ID)         TOTAL_ACC
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT T.TXN_PK)          TOTAL_TXN
  ,SUM(AM_AMOUNT)                    TOTAL_AMT
FROM T_HEADER  T
    ,CUST_MASTER A 
    ,TX_DETAILS1 D1
    ,TX_DETAILS2 D2
    ,CPG_MASTER C
WHERE   A.TYPE  =  0      
AND     T.CUST_ID = A.CUST_ID
AND     T.TXN_PK= 5001
AND     T.TXN_PK= D1.TXN_PK
AND     T.TXN_PK= D2.TXN_PK
AND     D1.CPG_PK = C.CPG_PK
AND     D1.OP = 1 
GROUP BY 
 YEAR
,MONTH
,WEEK
,C.CPG_PK
,C.DEP_PK
,t.CUST_ID 
,D1.R_ID
,Decode(d2.AT_CODE,'3',FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE))
,decode(d2.AT_CODE,'2',FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE))
,decode(d2.AT_CODE,'1',FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE))
,decode(FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE), 2 , d2.AT_CODE)
,decode(FUNC1.GET_ATT(d2.AT_CODE,D2.VAL_CODE), 5 , d2.AT_CODE)
```

the generated output as follows

```
YEAR    MONTH   WEEK    CPG DEPT    CUST_ID R_ID    P1  IC  B1  P2  B2  TOTAL_ACC   TOTAL_TXN   TOTAL_AMT
2012    08  32  127 -1  10019   3665                    134 1   1   
2012    08  32  127 -1  10019   3665                    135 1   1   
2012    08  32  127 -1  10019   3665            723         1   1   
2012    08  32  127 -1  10019   3665        714             1   1   
2012    08  32  127 -1  10019   3665    21                  1   1   
2012    08  32  128 -1  10019   3665                    134 1   1   
2012    08  32  128 -1  10019   3665                    135 1   1   
2012    08  32  128 -1  10019   3665            723         1   1   
2012    08  32  128 -1  10019   3665        714             1   1   
2012    08  32  128 -1  10019   3665    21                  1   1
```

here the values are repeating i tried with possible group by.

the required ouput is

```
YEAR    MONTH   WEEK    CPG DEPT    CUST_ID R_ID    P1  IC  B1  P2  B2  TOTAL_ACC   TOTAL_TXN   TOTAL_AMT
2012    08  32  127 -1  10019   3665    21  714 723     134 1   1   
2012    08  32  127 -1  10019   3665    21  714 723     135 1   1   
2012    08  32  128 -1  10019   3665    21  714 723     134 1   1   
2012    08  32  128 -1  10019   3665    21  714 723     135 1   1
```

the main thing is year,month,week,cpg,dept,cust_id,r_id ,p1,ic,b1,p2,b2 it should be unique row. Is it achievable using analytical functions or do I need to write `pl/sql`

Comment: is my question is meaning ful ?

Answer (score 0):

Saw this, and I think I have an answer for you.  So what you are wanting is SQL to take a table that looks like:

```
Year  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
2012    A
2012           B
2012                  C
```

And transform it into:

```
Year  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
2012    A      B      C
```

What you can do (for the above example) is the following:

```
Select
    Year,
    Max(Col_1) as C1,
    Max(Col_2) as C2,
    Max(Col_3) as C3
From
    Table_1
Group By
    Year
```

This will work with out trouble if you ONLY have 1 record in each.  Otherwise, you might have to figure out if you need to use `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, or an alternative aggregation function.

If all the data was in one column and you wanted it in one column, you could use a similar technique:

Table_1

```
Year  Col_1 
2012    A
2012    B
2012    C
```

Code

```
Select
    Year,
    Max(Case When Col_1 = 'A' Then 'A' End) as A_Col,
    Max(Case When Col_1 = 'B' Then 'B' End) as B_Col,
    Max(Case When Col_1 = 'C' Then 'C' End) as C_Col
From
    Table_1
Group By
    Year
```

Note that `Decodes` should work in place of `Case` statements, but I think `Case`s are easier to read.